# How to limit the size of subprocess stdout and stderr in python

Tags: python, linux, subprocess, stdout, apparmor

I need to run applications submitted by users. My code looks like:

```
def run_app(app_path):
    inp = open("app.in", "r")
    otp = open("app.out", "w")

    return subprocess.call(app_path, stdout=otp, stdin=inp)
```

Now since I have no control over what users will submit, I want to restrict the size of the output of the application. Other things like trying to access unauthorized system resources and abusing of CPU cycles are being restricted by apparmor rule enforcement. The maximum time allowed to run is being handled by parent process (in python). Now a rogue application can still try to flood the server system by writing a lot of data to its stdout knowing the the stdout is being saved to a file.

I do not want to use AppArmors RLIMIT or anything in kernel mode for stdout/stderr files. It would be great to be able to do it from python using standard library.

I am currently thinking about creating a subclass of file and on each write check how much data has been written already to the stream. Or create a memory mapped file with maximum length set.

But I am feeling there may be a simpler way to restrict file size I do not see it yet.

Comment: Can you pipe the output through [`head`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/head)?

Comment: @Leon head will work. I was looking for something that says outp.maxsize = 10000 . That way its very simple. I may end up using RLIMIT or one friend shared a link about /etc/security/limits - either one will require some more config.

Answer (score 2):

Subclassing `file` or creating other pseudo-file Python object will not work at all, since the file will be consumed in the subprocess  - and therefore it must be an O.S. file, not a Python class object. Subprocess  won't send your Python object for the other process to use.

And while Python has native and simple support to memory-mapping files, through the `mmap` module, memory mapping is not meant for this: you can specify the size of the file that is mirrored to memory, but you that does not limit writting to the file at all: excess data will simply be written to disk and not be mapped. (And, again, you pass to the subprocess the disk-file, not the mmap object). It would be possible to create a file with a sentinel value at some point, and keep a thread checking if the sentinel is overwritten, at which point, it could kill the subprocess - but I doubt that would be reliable.

Then, there are disk-activity monitoring tools, such as inotify: you could use [pyinotify](https://github.com/seb-m/pyinotify/wiki/Tutorial) to a handler on your main process that would be called whenever the file is accessed. The downside: there is no event for 'file write' - just  'file acessed' - I am not sure if any of the possible events would be triggered by incremental writting of the file. And, nonetheless, if the child process would do all of its writting in a single system call, you'd just be notified too late anyway.

So, what I can think of that would work is: create a file in an artificially limited file-system.  That way, the OS will block writing when max-size is exceeded.

Under Linux, you can pre-create a file with the desired size +  some overhead, create an FS on it, and mount it with the "loop" interface - then just create your stdout and sterr files inside that filesystem, and call your child process.

You could pre-create and pre-mount a pool of such filesystems to be used as needed - or, you could even create them dynamically - but that would require the steps of creating the FS host file, creating a file-system structure on it (mkfs) and mounting it - all of this could be a lot of overhead.

All in all, maybe you are better simply using Apparmor's own rlimit settings.

Comment: Good points about file and mmap. I did not think about the overhead of bringing the output stream to python space from native file handle.

Your idea about restricting filesystem may be an option - I can just create an in memory fs with size limit - that way I wont need to save bigger files to any disk. I am not sure yet if I need to keep the file for future reference- in that case I may copy to final location. I am reconsidering apparmor solution since I just need to add simpl,e rules to the existing config.