# Write x lines of subprocess stdout to a file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm writing a python script that runs a command using subprocess module and then writes the output to a file. Since the output is too big, I want to write just x last lines of the output that contains the wanted information.

```
import subprocess
outFile=open('output.txt', 'w')
proc=subprocess.Popen(command, cwd=rundir, stdout=outFile)
```

The above code writes the whole output to a file (which is very very large), but what I want is just an x number of lines from the end of the output.

EDIT:
I know that I can post-process the file afterward, but what I want really is to write just the lines I need from the beginning without handling all those data.

Comment: How about using the batch command suffix `> stdOut.txt` and then reading the `stdOut.txt` file?

Comment: That also redirects the whole output to a file, but what I want is just a specific portion of the output.

Comment: You will not avoid some processing.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to store the output in a variable and then do some processing. The Python Interpreter will take care of all the data that is produced - even if it is larger than your RAM.

---

**CODE**

```py
with open('output.txt', 'w') as fobj:
    out = subprocess.check_output(command).rstrip().splitlines()
    fobj.write('\n'.join(out[-MAX_LINES:]))
```

---

**EXPLANATION**

- The function `subprocess.check_output` returns the console output as string.
- The method `str.rstrip()` returns the the string lack of trailing whitespaces. So the parameter `MAX_LINES` has control of the last non-empty lines.
- The method `str.splitlines()` returns a list of strings, each represents one line.
- `out[-MAX_LINES:]`

  - When `MAX_LINES > len(out)`, this will return the whole output as list.

---

**COMMENT**

*Always use context managers* (`with ...`)!!! This is more safe for file management.

Comment: When he says that the file is "very very large", that is because he does not want to process it fully, but your solution puts it into memory which I thinh is not doable for him.

Comment: @Lenormju The Python Interpreter will do the steps necessary process all the data.

Answer (score 0):

You can either truncate the file after it has been fully written, or give an [io.StringIO](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.StringIO) to your process, which you can `getvalue()` and then write only the lines you want.

Comment: That is not different from post-processing the written file, which I want to avoid, is there a way to specify a part of the output in the stdout option of subprocess?

Comment: According to the documentation (https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor), there is no way to do it there, maybe check this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/42173309/11384184) but is looks like there is no easy solution.